# flutter web :How to find iframeElement to replace it's src

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a flutter project that i added web support to it. Now in my page i have 2 button.I want to when user clicked on each button, a web page shown.So in order to i create custom widget :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("url is ------> ${url}");
    isAddedElement();
    _iframeElement.height = double.maxFinite.toString();
    _iframeElement.width = double.maxFinite.toString();
    _iframeElement.src = url;
    _iframeElement.style.border = 'none';
    _iframeElement.id = 'iframe';

    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
    _iframeWidget = HtmlElementView(
      // key: UniqueKey(),
      viewType: 'iframeElement',
    );
    return SizedBox(
      height: 600,
      width: 600,
      child: _iframeWidget,
    );
  }
```

in`isAddedElement` method i want to check `iframeElement.id = 'iframe'` is exist or not?If exist i want to change src with the new web page:

```
  bool isAddedElement() {
    IFrameElement frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
    if (frame != null) frame.src = url;
  }
```

but `document.querySelector('iframe')` always return null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query returns `null`, most likely because flutter adds the `HtmlElementView` widget inside a `shadowDom` and these elements are not available directly in the `document` scope.

In order to access the element you need to go via a `shadowroot` which is usually placed under custome tag called `flutter-platform-view`.

So the following approaches may work.

#### Accessing via `flt-platform-view`

Try to access the iframe element as shown below.

`document.getElementsByTagName('flutter-platform-view')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('iframe');`

#### Accessing the IframeElement instance

You already have the reference of `IframeElement` instance and can check what you need with it as shown below.

```dart
  bool isAddedElement() {
    //IFrameElement frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
    if (_iframeElement!= null && _iframeElement.src == null) _iframeElement.src = url;
  }
```

However I don't understand why in your code you are calling the `isAddedElement()` even before setting up the IframeElement.

You can find more details about the why its put behind a shadow dom in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40080) in github.

Here is full working demo using the first approach. The live version is available as a [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/XWKBPqN) demo

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: IframeDemo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IframeDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyWidget();
  }
}

class MyWidget extends State<IframeDemo> {
  String _url;
  IFrameElement _iframeElement;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter';
    _iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..src = _url
      ..id = 'iframe'
      ..style.border = 'none';
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
  }

  void updateUrl(String page) {
    setState(() {      
      // building a new url
      _url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$page';
      
      // Setting the url to the src field of the iframe element.
      HtmlElement elem = document.getElementsByTagName('flt-platform-view')[0];
      IFrameElement ifrelem = elem.shadowRoot.getElementById('iframe');
      ifrelem..src = _url;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('url is $_url');

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: Text('Show Twitter wiki'),
              onPressed: () {
                updateUrl('Twitter');
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 50,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              child: Text('Show Facebook Wiki'),
              onPressed: () {
                updateUrl('Facebook');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 600,
          width: 600,
          child: HtmlElementView(
            // key: UniqueKey(),
            viewType: 'iframeElement',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When i add `document.getElementsByTagName('flutter-platform-view')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('iframe');` In `shadowRoot` i got  `The getter 'shadowRoot' isn't defined for the type 'Node'.`  https://pasteboard.co/JyXZGpX.png @Abhilash Chandran

Comment: I am using `import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';` @Abhilash Chandran

Comment: And `document.getElementsByTagName('flutter-platform-view')` returns null. I also tried `document.getElementsByTagName('flt-platform-view')` and this is also return null @Abhilash Chandran

Comment: This is devtools info https://pasteboard.co/JyYeHH9.png

Comment: this could be an an issue where you are calling `isAddedElement`. Let me see I can put up an example for you.

Comment: This is minimal complete code without isAddedElement. I appropriated to fix this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PaOhU4T5WnqxdxKSMGWgZcNu-DQHKtvs/view?usp=sharing @@Abhilash Chandran

Comment: I changed location of using document.getElementsByTagName : https://pasteboard.co/JyYFlcX.png   `HtmlCollection[] is empty @Abhilash Chandran

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check in the live version that it works. :) Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks bro but what version is your sdk ? Becuse when i used all code in new project in platformViewRegistry got error `The name 'platformViewRegistry' is being referenced through the prefix 'ui', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that prefix.
Try correcting the prefix or importing the library that defines 'platformViewRegistry'.` https://pasteboard.co/JyZzI1H.png @Abhilash Chandran

Comment: This is a know issue that only appears in the IDE. Check this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41563#issuecomment-626765363) in github for a workaround to keep the analyzer in the IDE happy. This is issue there in all the flutter-sdk's since flutter web launched as beta.

Comment: It can't find any `flt-platform-view` in the page and this exception is thrown: `Exception: RangeError: Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0`

Comment: It's not working now, maybe after the stable update of flutter web.